# How to view hidden files in the Windows Explorer

Tags: windows

[Here is the path for one of my python files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBfp6.png)

[But when I follow that path, I can only go until  'c:\users\midhu' . After that I cannot find any further files, where can I find those files in the path?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8cWj.png)

On a side note, I may have accidentally messed up my environmental path variable path. Does it have anything to with files not showing up?

Please help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[View hidden files and folders in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5#WindowsVersion=Windows_10)

Comment: Yo, found em. How can I unhide them?
My python packages exist in those folders and I cannot use them while programming.